# How to safely kill adb.exe process on windows

Tags: android

My windows PC is having 'n' number of adb.exe running while running my android test suite. This is causing adb to stop in middle

Please tell me How to safely kill this process and ensure remaining test suite execution would continue safely

Comment: Go to Android SDK location and run `cmd`. Try this command `adb kill-server`

Answer (score 2):

Command for killing the server process is:
adb kill-server

Answer (score 0):

save your data in your ide. close it.
close all instances of adb. disconnect devices.
launch IDE(Eclipse or whatever)
let it load.
connect device.

it doesnt matter how you close it i force close the adb all the time. try to avoid closing while data is bieng transferred and youll be fine

in other words, CTRL-ALT-DEL the extras